# Can a grabbed creature stand up from prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, grapple

One of my players, a thri-kreen berserker, uses [Run Down](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=14410) and [World Serpent's Grasp](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3528) to prone enemies. He then used his action point to make a grab attack, with the intent of holding the enemy to the ground.

Grab says it immobilizes the target.  I allowed the grab to prevent the target from standing because it made sense. Can anyone explain why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Matt. We've edited your question to be clearer. Check out our [FAQ] for some tips.

Answer (score 7):

**Grabbing someone does NOT stop them from standing up from prone.**

From PHB1, pg290, describing the `grab` action:

> *Hit:* The enemy is immobilized until it escapes or you end the grab.

Grab inflicts immobilize, nothing else (barring some brawler fighter feats).

From PHB1, pg277:

> **Immobilized:** You can't move from your space, although you can teleport and can be forced to move by a pull, a push, or a slide.

While standing up *is* a move action, it does *not* entail leaving your space, so being grabbed/immobilized does **not** stop you from standing up.

There's a fighter feat, [`Pin Down`](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=948) (Dragon 368), that specifically allows this:

> **Benefit:** A prone target you are grabbing can't stand until you end the grab or until it escapes.